# We know that a son cannot claim self defence if he kills his father who is about to rob him. What about his mother

Tags: gezel-stealing, murder, maseches-pesachim

The g'moro in psochim 2b says that a father who goes to rob his son, will not kill him and therefore if the son kills his father he cannot claim self defence. What about if a mother goes to rob her son and the son kills her, can he claim self defence if he kills her.

Comment: -1 for a lack of punctuation in my estimation this is written in terrible english its very hard to read, don't you think.

Comment: I dont think so anymore.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1384&st=&pgnum=197

Comment: Why might you think it would be different?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 6):

Mabit (vol. 1 ch. 339) writes that this applies specifically to the father; not to the mother.
However the Gemara Sanhedrin 72b writes that anytime that one knows that the intruder is a very close beloved friend who wouldn't harm him, then he cannot kill him, so Mabit would agree that if one has such a relationship with his mother then it would be forbidden to kill her.
Mabit is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1384&st=&pgnum=197)

Comment: Excellent link following! +1

Comment: +1 Magid mishna says same about a son who has this love for his father. It just struck me how interesting the wording of the drasha is. Barur licha hadavar kashemesh. In reality, we are discussing someone who does not know the extent of the love so a son who has this question about his father's love for him should assume he won't kill him etc, as rashi points out top of amud beis, the son is misupik. This is what we call barur kashemesh!

Comment: Look at Rashi's wording again.  It is one of the stranger Rashis I have seen for he says dont kill him misafek, for he certainly doesnt intend to kill you; so which is it: certain or uncertain.

Comment: I actually didnt see the link.  I knew I remembered someone saying it from last time I learned Ben Sorer, and then used the online Bar Ilan to find it. I'll add the link though.

Comment: mevaqesh -- if you want someone to see your response to their comment on a post they didn't write, you should write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure if @user6591 or Matt saw your response to their comments. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2067/5323 for more info.

Comment: @Matt ^^^^^ (*max one ping per comment*)

Comment: @user6591 
 
Look at Rashi's wording again. It is one of the stranger Rashis I have seen for he says dont kill him misafek, for he certainly doesnt intend to kill you; so which is it: certain or uncertain.

Comment: @mevaqesh that was my point. But I'm not asking it as a question, just pointing it out as a haara. If the homeowner is certain like the sun of the intent of the intruder, he should act accordingly. If this homeowner is uncertain about the intent of the intruder, then there is an assumption made for him based on who the intruder is, either his father or son. However it is clear to him like the sun that this person is not working within the normal behaviors ascribed to this relative, in this case again act according to intent, not according to assumptions of relationship.